# Importrange multiple files and query not pulling data

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

Im trying to import more than a 100 files into one masterfile.

The problem I'm having is that when I use query null to filter blank rows, some cells return as blank (probably because the entries to that cell's column may either be a text or number string)

Is there any way around this so that the query will just take the values/any string within the cell. I'd hate to see a lot of blank rows from the import of more than 100 files!

Appreciate any help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

before using QUERY you can force the text format with TO_TEXT so:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TO_TEXT({
 IMPORTRANGE("id1"; "A1:A"); 
 IMPORTRANGE("id2"; "A1:A"); 
 IMPORTRANGE("id3"; "A1:A")}); "where Col1 is not null"; ))
```

keep in mind that every of your 100 importranges needs to be run as standalone fx prior to using the above formula to connect your sheets by allowing the access